# Changing Text Color On Click

Tags: javascript, text, colors

I'm trying to change the text from black to blue when I click. I have it as an "if" statement and I know it doesn't need to be an "if" statement, but I'm just wondering why it doesn't work. I'm just asking, "If this color is black, change it to blue."

```js
var myvar = document.getElementById('thisdiv');

myvar.onclick = function myfunction() {
  if (myvar.style.color == "#000000") {
    myvar.style.color = "#0000FF";
  }
}
```

```css
.mydiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv" id="thisdiv">Click Me</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jonfoster9999/cywcd175/3/)

I'm not really looking for a solution to make it go from black to blue as I'm sure there's other ways I could figure out to do it, but more just wondering why the way I have it isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`style` only holds styles that were added using the `style` attribute in the HTML. It doesn't contain the computed style from applying `<style>` tags or stylesheets.

To get the computed style, use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). Note this is read-only.

```js
var myvar = document.getElementById('thisdiv');

myvar.onclick = function myfunction() {
  if (window.getComputedStyle(myvar).color === "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
    myvar.style.color = "#0000FF";
  }
}
```

```css
.mydiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv" id="thisdiv">Click Me</div>
```

A better strategy though is to add or remove CSS classes to elements, so that you get separate presentation from functionality.

Comment: so would the "if" come back as true the way I had it if the color was set in the style tag in the head of the html of the document , rather than in a linked css page?

Comment: No. It only looks at the `style` attribute of the HTML element. A better practice though is to make a CSS class, and then add or remove that class to change styles.

Comment: nevermind I read your explanation more clearly....thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: @JonathanFoster Great! Just an FYI, when an answer solves a question, it's normal for the asker to click the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Thank you!!!! I checked the box, and thanks to everyone else too, this site is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the reason the code is not working is because `myvar.style.color` is `undefined`.  When you use a stylesheet, it doesn't affect the JavaScript `style` properties, which should be the same as the styles defined in the `style` attribute of the element.  What you want is something like the following.

```
// undefined!="#0000ff", success
if(myvar.style.color!="#0000ff") {
    myvar.style.color = "#0000ff";
}
```

If you want to use JQuery, you can try something like the following.

```
// JQuery always returns opaque colors in rgb(r, g, b) form
// regardless of the original format.
if($(myvar).css("color")=="rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
    myvar.style.color = "#0000ff";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest using an additional class for this, to account for its state.

```
var myvar = document.getElementById('thisdiv');

myvar.onclick = function myfunction() {
    /* if (myvar.className === ""){
        myval.className = "active";
    } else {
        myvar.className = "";
    } */
    // Same as below, toggle the class of #thisdiv from active to blank
    myvar.className = myvar.className === "" ? "active" : "";
}



.mydiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mydiv.active{
  color: #0000ff;
}
```

You could also probably make use of the :visited pseudo selector and get rid of the click function entirely. You'd need to make your div one big link though. Something like this;

```
<a class="mydiv" id="thisdiv">Click Me</a>

.mydiv{
  display:block; /* since it's a link and will be inline by default */
}
.mydiv:visited{
  color: #0000ff;
}
```